# How to define the specify page of picture in LaTex?

Tags: latex

I am writing a book using latex,I want to 
 move picture to specific page to print with color,and without picture to print black-white.how to define all picture of this book on specific page.This is my picture define code:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{reduxloggerexample.png}
    \caption{Redux Logger打印效果}
    \label{fig:reduxloggerexample}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Wrong place to ask. Should be migrated to https://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: *All* pictures? You need to provide more context - do you want to specify a page number and have the `figure` show up on that page? How should multiple figures be handled?